# Why does Scala's semicolon inference fail here?

Tags: scala

On compiling the following code with Scala 2.7.3,

```
package spoj

object Prime1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def isPrime(n: Int) = (n != 1) && (2 to n/2 forall (n % _ != 0))
    val read = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
    var nTests = read nextInt // [*]
    while(nTests > 0) {
      val (start, end) = (read nextInt, read nextInt)
      start to end filter(isPrime(_)) foreach println
      println
      nTests -= 1
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following compile time error :

```
PRIME1.scala:8: error: illegal start of simple expression
    while(nTests > 0) {
    ^
PRIME1.scala:14: error: block must end in result expression, not in definition
  }
  ^
two errors found
```

When I add a semicolon at the end of the line commented as `[*]`, the program compiles fine. Can anyone please explain why does Scala's semicolon inference fail to work on that particular line?

Comment: Just off-the-topic, `2 to n/2` can be replaced with `2 to Math.sqrt(n)` — it is the canonical solution, although I don't know if it will provide better performance (I think, it won't).

Comment: i know this is an OLD thread, but could you explicitly put the semicolon after the `read nextInt` line? or is this a problem because there is no argument provided to `nextInt`?

Comment: @Ramy: Read the answers.

Comment: @missingfaktor: it's actually at the bottom of your question. (+1 - thanks)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is it because scala is assuming that you are using the syntax `a foo b` (equivalent to `a.foo(b)`) in your call to `readInt`. That is, it assumes that the `while` loop is the argument to `readInt` (recall that every expression has a type) and hence the last statement is a declaration:

```
var ntests = read nextInt x
```

where`x` is your while block.

I must say that, as a point of preference, I've now returned to using the usual `a.foo(b)` syntax over `a foo b` *unless specifically working with a DSL which was designed with that use in mind* (like actors' `a ! b`). It makes things much clearer in general and you don't get bitten by weird stuff like this!

Comment: i know this is an OLD thread, but could you explicitly put the semicolon after the read nextInt line? or is this a problem because there is no argument provided to nextInt?

Answer (score 11):

Additional comment to the answer by oxbow_lakes...

```
var ntests = read nextInt()
```

Should fix things for you as an alternative to the semicolon

Answer (score 8):

To add a little more about the semicolon inference, Scala actually does this in two stages. First it infers a special token called `nl` by the language spec. The parser allows `nl` to be used as a statement separator, as well as semicolons. However, `nl` is also permitted in a few other places by the grammar. In particular, a single `nl` is allowed after infix operators when the first token on the next line can start an expression -- and `while` can start an expression, which is why it interprets it that way. Unfortunately, although `while` can start a expression, a while statement cannot be used in an infix expression, hence the error. Personally, it seems a rather quirky way for the parser to work, but there's quite plausibly a sane rationale behind it for all I know!

As yet another option to the others suggested, putting a blank newline between your `[*]` line and the `while` line will also fix the problem, because only a single `nl` is permitted after infix operators, so multiple `nl`s forces a different interpretation by the parser.