# What does "recursive method <method name> needs type" in Scala mean?

Tags: scala

When I try to omit dots from method invocations, like in this example program:

```
object Test extends Application {
  val baz = new Baz
  var foo = baz bar
  println(foo)
}

class Baz {
  def bar = "bar"
}
```

I get strange errors. The first one is `error: recursive method foo needs type: println foo` and the other one is `error: type mismatch; found: Unit, required: Int, println(foo)`. The first error is in some strange way fixed if i specify that the type of `foo` should be String. The second one won't go away before I put a dot between `baz` and `bar`. What is the cause of this? Why does Scala think that `baz bar` is a recursive method?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246212/why-does-scalas-semicolon-inference-fail-here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that if you omit the dots the code is ambigous. The compiler will treat the expression as

```
var foo = baz.bar(println(foo))
```

thus `foo` is defined recursively and `StringOps.apply` method needs an `Int` argument (`String` will be implicitly converted to `StringOps` as `String` has no `apply` method).

You should only use the operator like syntax when calling methods that take one non-`Unit` argument to avoid such ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I had no idea Scala would try to put lines together like that. I thought it treated line breaks as a semicolon. I experimented a bit, and the problem could also be solved by inserting a semicolon after `val foo = baz bar`.

Comment: Scala normally treats line breaks as whitespace but the compiler tries to infer semicolons where needed. In your case this just does not work well together with the type inference.