# Proper way for looping in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

Suppose I have an array of strings in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/):

```
val strings = Array[String]("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
```

What I need is to make a new array which elements will be obtained as a concatenation of each three (any number) consequent elements of the first array, which should result in `("123", "456", "7")`

Being new to Scala I wrote the following code which was neither concise nor effective:

```
var step = 3
val strings = Array[String]("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
val newStrings = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]

for (i <- 0 until strings.length by step) {
  var elem = ""
  for (k <- 0 until step if i + k < strings.length) {
    elem += strings(i + k)
  }
  newStrings += elem
}
```

What would be the Scala way for doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
strings.grouped(3).map(_.mkString).toArray
```

or

```
strings grouped 3 map (_.mkString) toArray
```

I personally prefer the first version :)

Answer (score 4):

```
strings grouped 3 map (_.mkString)
```

or (in order to really get an `Array` back)

```
(strings grouped 3 map (_.mkString)).toArray
```

Comment: Yeah,your version is dot-free :) But you'll need an .toArray statement - your version returns an Iterator instead of Array.

Comment: Yeah, but I didn’t want to wrap the whole statement in parentheses just for that. :)

Comment: Fwiw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233227/scala-infix-vs-dot-notation/10313469#10313469.

Comment: You don't need to wrap it :) It allows one trailing call.

Comment: @Rogach: Now. But who knows what the future brings. http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/modularizing-language-features.html

Comment: @Rogach, also you need to add a semicolon after that, or else it may cause issues like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246212/why-does-scalas-semicolon-inference-fail-here).

Comment: And our Scala starts looking like Lisp with extra parentheses :/

Answer (score 3):

... or use *sliding*

```
val strings = Array[String]("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
strings.sliding (3, 3) .map (_.mkString).toArray

res19: Array[String] = Array(123, 456, 7)
```

Sliding: You take 3, and move forward 3. Variants:

```
scala> strings.sliding (3, 2) .map (_.mkString).toArray
res20: Array[String] = Array(123, 345, 567)
```

take 3, but forward 2

```
scala> strings.sliding (2, 3) .map (_.mkString).toArray
res21: Array[String] = Array(12, 45, 7)
```

take 2, forward 3 (thereby skipping every third)